# Unable to pass props from parent to child and save it in state of child component

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to develop a website for fetching GitHub data, but I'm having problem in updating the component that shows data `Formdata` component. It doesn't seem to be updating form some reasons.

**App:**

```
export default class App extends Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    uname:'',
    udata:'',
  };
  this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
  this.getUser = this.getUser.bind(this);
}

getUser(){
  fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${this.state.uname}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data =>  this.setState({udata:data}))
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
}

handleInput(event){
      this.setState({
        uname:event.target.value
      });
}
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header></Header>
      <Form handleInput={this.handleInput} uname={this.state.uname} getUser={this.getUser}></Form>
      <Formdata udata={this.state.udata}></Formdata>
    </div>
  )
}
}
```

**Form:**

```
export default function Form(props) {

   const {getUser, handleInput, uname} = props;
    return (
        <div className="form">
            <input className="textbar" placeholder="Search for username" value={uname} onChange={handleInput} name="uname"></input>
            <button className="button" onClick={getUser} >Search</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Formdata:**

```
export default class Formdata extends Component {
    
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            follower:'',
            following:'',
            public_repos:'',
            visit_page:'',
            avatar:''
        }
        this.updateUser = this.updateUser.bind(this);
    };
    componentDidMount(props){
       this.updateUser();
    }
    
    updateUser(){
        this.setState({follower:this.props.udata.followers});
        this.setState({following:this.props.udata.following});
        this.setState({public_repos:this.props.udata.public_repos});
        this.setState({visit_page:this.props.udata.url});
        this.setState({avatar:this.props.udata.avatar_url});
        console.log(this.props.udata);

    }
    render() {   
        return (
            <div>
                <img className="imge" src= {this.state.avatar} alt="  "></img>
                <div className="details">
                    <div className="compon">Followers: {this.state.followers}</div>
                    <div className="compon">Following: {this.state.following}</div>
                    <div className="compon">public repos" {this.state.public_repos}</div>
                </div>
                <div className="urls">Page:{this.state.visit_page}</div>  
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how to update component `Formdata` on clicking search button in `Form` component.

Comment: Your class is named `formdata` but you're using it in the app JSX like `<Formdata />`. You should use the same casing.

Comment: did it, thanks, but still not working

Comment: i tried that but didn't worked

Comment: like the answer provided by @codeth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do not copy `props` into `state`**, use the `props` directly in your JSX:

```
div>
    <img className="imge" src= {this.props.udata.avatar} alt="  "></img>
    <div className="details">
        <div className="compon">Followers: {this.props.udata.followers}</div>
        <div className="compon">Following: {this.props.udata.following}</div>
        <div className="compon">public repos" {this.props.udata.public_repos}</div>
    </div>
    <div className="urls">Page:{this.props.udata.visit_page}</div>
</div>
```

If you copy props into state, you are creating redundant copy of props and it is difficult to keep props and state in sync. And it is a React anti-pattern.

Just make sure `this.props.udata` is not `undefined`, it is ok if it is empty object `{}`. If it is undefined, put a check / conditional rendering.

[anti-pattern-unconditionally-copying-props-to-state](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#anti-pattern-unconditionally-copying-props-to-state)

Answer (score 2):

**Full Working App: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kojwu6?file=src%2FApp.js)**

[image]

```js
import React, { Component, useEffect } from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      uname: "",
      udata: ""
    };
    this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
    this.getUser = this.getUser.bind(this);
  }

  getUser() {
    fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${this.state.uname}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data =>
        this.setState({ udata: data }, () => {
          console.log(this.state.udata);
        })
      )
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  }

  handleInput(event) {
    this.setState(
      {
        uname: event.target.value
      },
      () => {
        console.log(this.state.uname);
      }
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Form
          handleInput={this.handleInput}
          uname={this.state.uname}
          getUser={this.getUser}
        />
        <Formdata udata={this.state.udata} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Form = props => {
  const { getUser, handleInput, uname } = props;
  return (
    <div className="form">
      <input
        className="textbar"
        placeholder="Search for username"
        value={uname}
        onChange={handleInput}
        name="uname"
      />
      <button className="button" onClick={getUser}>
        Search
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const Formdata = ({ udata }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(udata.login));
  }, [udata]);

  return (
    <div style={styles.card}>
      {udata.login ? (
        <div style={styles.cardImg}>
          <div>
            <img
              style={styles.img}
              className="imge"
              src={udata?.avatar_url}
              alt="  "
            />
          </div>
          <div className="details">
            <div className="compon">Followers: {udata?.followers}</div>
            <div className="compon">Following: {udata?.following}</div>
            <div className="compon">Public repos: {udata?.public_repos}</div>

            <div className="urls">Page: {udata?.url}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <p>No Data Available</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

const styles = {
  card: {
    display: "flex",
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(21,21,21,0.2)",
    padding: 10,
    marginTop: 10,
    borderRadius: 5
  },
  cardImg: {
    display: "flex",
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    overflow: "hidden",
    textOverflow: "ellipsis",
    color: "rgba(0,0,0,0.7)"
  },
  img: {
    marginRight: 10,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    borderRadius: 10,
    overflow: "hidden"
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`Formdata.updateUser()` isn't being called at any point. You probably just need to call it in `componentDidMount()`:

```
export default class Formdata extends Component {
    
    ...

    componentDidMount(props){
       this.updateUser();
    }
    
    updateUser(){
        this.setState({follower:this.props.udata.followers});
        this.setState({following:this.props.udata.following});
        this.setState({public_repos:this.props.udata.public_repos});
        this.setState({visit_page:this.props.udata.url});
        this.setState({avatar:this.props.udata.avatar_url});
        console.log(this.props.udata);

    }
    
    ...
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? What error messages are you getting?

Comment: not getting error messages, code is working but there is nothing happening after i click search button

Comment: but when i check state value in app.js then its chaged to data fetched